# How to trigger job on specific job failure using "when: on_failure"?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am working on CICD and for some reason, we want to trigger a job on another job failure.

In yaml file, I have specified "when: on_failure" but I am not able to find a solution to specify job name.

Something like: "when: on_failure: Job_Name".

Now, my 'on failure' job runs on any job failure.

Answer (score 0):

If `job1` is the first job which may fail and `job2` is the next one which should be triggered then I'd suggest the following plan:

- execute `job2` always with no regards if any of previous jobs failed or not ( use `when: always` for that).
- make `job1` to save its result (fail or success) to the artefact file which should be available for `job2`
- in `job2` do required actions only based on the content of the artefact from the previous step: if it's failure then do what you need to do, if it's success then just skip.
  Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

````
  script:
    - some commands
    - ...
    - touch $CI_PROJECT_DIR/success
  after_script:
    - |
      if [ -e success ]; then
        echo on success
      else
        echo on failure
      fi
```
````

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get "on failure" regardless of whether the script succeeds.