# Gitlab CI pipeline: add message to discussion from CI pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is it possible to add a message to the merge request discussion?
(Something like notification about pipeline failure)
I haven't found anything like this in .gitlab-ci.yaml reference, but maybe I just don't look for the right name of the thing.

I have found API to post a new merge request thread, but it doesn't seem be available from the docker container of the job.

Answer (score 2):

It depend on how complex or detailed you want the message to be.

For something as simple as a pipeline failure, you can turn on [notifications](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/notifications.html#issue--epics--merge-request-events) if that's what you're looking for.

To post a message, you can definitely make use of the API. If your runner/job can reach your instance, you will need to use the full link of your instance with a [personal access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) at least until [pipeline permissions are more flexible](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/35067).

Another alternative is to use a plugin or add-on. For example, GitLab itself uses [danger](https://github.com/danger/danger), which is ruby gem meant to do code review as part of the pipeline.

But you can see [in the danger folder of the GitLab repository](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/tree/master/danger) that it's been extended to do things like post a message to suggest a changelog entry, suggest reviewers, etc.

So that's getting the message to the thread.

For triggering it on failure, there are a couple of different answer over [in this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55630522/how-to-trigger-job-on-specific-job-failure-using-when-on-failure) which I think should help.